# SVProgressHUD not showing progress

Tags: ios8, svprogresshud

SVProgressHUD is not showing progress as expected.

Should I be doing something different?

```
[SVProgressHUD showProgress:(count/total) status:@"Downloading..."];
```

Is there a different method to call to set the progress?

Answer (score 3):

If it's not showing up at all and you're calling it from viewDidLoad, dispatching it into the main thread queue worked for me.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^() {
    [SVProgressHUD showProgress:(count/total) status:@"Downloading..."];
});
```

If it's showing up but the progress is 0, you should rule out an integer arithmetic rounding error by casting total or count to a double before division.

Comment: It's weird because earlier with iOS 7 we never did that and it worked just fine. Now we need to call an asynchronous thread to invoke it?? meh!! +1 for the solution.